# Azure Data Factory Managed VNet for on-premises resources: complexity of the setup

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network

I need to set up ADF with VNet integration.
Fortunately, there is now a Managed VNet feature that avoids creating a VM and hosting a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime on it.

Unfortunately, when I look into the requirements and the setup associated, it looks like it requires a Load Balancer and also Virtual Machines as stated in this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server

Is it really the only way to manage VNet integration with on-premises resources?

Answer (score 0):

As creating Load Balancer and VM are one of the few steps mentioned in the Microsoft Official document, hence this needs to be done when deploying ADF in VNet.
The reason why these two services required are mentioned below:

> A load balancer rule is used to define how traffic is distributed to
> the VMs. You define the frontend IP configuration for the incoming
> traffic and the backend IP pool to receive the traffic. The source and
> destination port are defined in the rule.

The virtual machine will be used as a backend server. When you will create VM, under **Network** settings you will be using the Load Balancer as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but what I'm not sure to understand is the requirement to have a VM and why we can't access directly the on-premises resources without having a VM?

Comment: Generally, there are 2 requirements for connecting ADF with on-prem SQL server. One, to copy/move the on-prem SQL DB data to Azure SQL DB. For this application there is no need to create any load balancer and VM. But, in another case if you want to access data from on-prem SQL server using ADF and connect it with any application, then VM will work as backend server and load balancer will be used to define how traffic is distributed to the VM.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that there is a need for a Load Balancer and VM Scale Set in order to access from ADF runtime to a local SQL Server instance. It looks like there are no other choices. Have you a link to a post or document where the setup is explained?

Comment: @AbhishekKhandave what would be the set up for just copy activity from on prem to azure sql? Is express route enough?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this with a workaround via linked servers.

Without having to run all these servers and services just to get access.

Premise is you need to have a site2site VPN setup.

We created Linked Servers in our Sql Managed Instance (with IP addresses, then renamed for hostname).

Now I can access the on prem db with `Select * from {{Hostname}}.{{Database}}.Table`